# Where is status data stored when going to sleep mode in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, sleep

When I click the Start button, select Power/sleep, where is the current state of computer stored: RAM, CMOS, or HDD?

When in sleep mode, I switch off power supply, remove hdd1(where the old OS is), connect hdd2(where the new OS is), switch on the power supply, power on the PC, can the state of old OS affect the state of new OS?

If all states of old OS are stored on hard drive, I think they would not affect the state of new OS.
But if part of them are stored in CMOS, they can affect the state of new OS?

If data are stored in RAM, can CMOS battery maintain the content of RAM after switching off the power supply?

If so, they would affect the state of new OS, too?

Comment: What research have you done? Power states are pretty well documented, including what they are, how they work, etc.

Comment: For instance, Sleep keeps the contents of RAM there in the RAM, using energy from the battery. Power loss during sleep will result in the current state being lost. Hibernate is a deeper sleep state, where the contents of memory are written to a file on the hard drive, and so the RAM doesn't need to remain powered. But, like I said, all this is really well documented online.

Comment: @music2myear yes, all you said can be found online, but I did not find if the sleep can change data in CMOS/BIOS. And I do not know if RAM content can be maintained by CMOS battery on motherboard. I'm using PC, not a laptop.

Comment: Sleep doesn't change anything. Sleep is a power state and it isn't writing anything to BIOS. The CMOS battery's only purpose is maintaining the BIOS contents. It doesn't run anything else. Your question seems to indicate several fundamental misunderstandings regarding computer architecture and power states and so cannot be answered as it is.

Comment: @music2myear I know sleep is a power state. What I want to know is what OS does to bring computer to the state. As far as I know, OS may change the behavior of BIOS to trigger timer  interrupt handler to do things such as bringing computer to hibernate state. You may not understand the sleep mechanism to a deep degree.

Comment: You cannot switch your drive during sleep without damaging your system. As a noted, in Sleep memory is kept active and retains its contents. Killing power means you're losing that, basically freezing the computer and then pulling power. Don't. Just don't.

Comment: @music2myear I encounter no problem switching between the two HDDs, even after cutting power. I'm just curious about if the two OSs affect each other's state in a way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Then you are not using sleep. That much is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late, but had a similar question and want to share what helped me.

Had 2 disks in my pc when I put it in sleep mode. Forgot about it and later removed the other (external) disk, not the one that has the OS on it. After that I could not startup the pc, no signal, no output whatsoever. Tried to put the external disk back but didn't help. Changed the OS disk with another functional but also no output on monitor. Had a spare RAM so I removed all disk's and try to boot with a new RAM and now I finally got startup signals but had no disk so it was waiting for an insert disk. Then tried the same with the RAMs I removed (have 2) and again got the startup signal but when I inserted the OS disk it went back where it was.

Was ready to reinstall windows but first I wanted to try to delete the hiberfil.sys file. Use WinDirStat or Explorer++ for it to find or change the options in basic Windows explorer, in View uncheck the Hide protected operating system files
After deletion, I booted up from that disk without a problem. Not sure why I could not boot from another disk. I use an old Gigabyte GA-G31M-ES2C motherboard. Also somewhere in the process I removed the CMOS battery for a few seconds, that might have helped

As far as I know your sleep state of the pc should be in the hiberfil.sys file and so it should not affect the state of new OS.

Comment: Sleep (S1 or S3 or, more recently S0ix) is very much unlike hibernation (S4). // Your story isn't relevant to this question. It just makes it hard to tell where the answer may be.